# Cant find drivers for ASUS p5rd2-vm/v2 on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers

It seems like there are no drivers for windows 7 on ASUS asus p5rd2-vm/v2 motherboard. What can I do?

Comment: What devices on the motherboard do you feel need a non-generic driver?  Just use the Vista drivers.

Comment: @Ramhound sound,video,LAN..

Comment: Unless the sound and lan controllers are not working you don't need drivers.  Use the general purpose ATI drivers for the Radeon X300.